# How to get a specific number of signers while testing smart contracts in Hardhat?

Tags: ethers.js, hardhat, rsk

I am developing my smart contracts in Hardhat and testing on [RSK Testnet](https://developers.rsk.co/kb/hardhat-setup-on-rsk/).
To create signer accounts, I am using a mnemonic seed phrase
and the following Hardhat configuration:
​

```js
require('@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox');
const { mnemonic } = require('./.secret.json');
​
/** @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig */
module.exports = {
  solidity: '0.8.16',
  networks: {
    hardhat: {},
    rsktestnet: {
      chainId: 31,
      url: 'https://public-node.testnet.rsk.co/',
      accounts: { // <-- here
        mnemonic,
        path: "m/44'/60'/0'/0",
      },
    },
  },
  // ...
};
```

​
In my tests, I usually use an `ethers.js` helper function
to get an array of signers in my tests:
​

```js
const signers = await hre.ethers.getSigners();
```

​
However this function returns 20 signer wallets.
Is there a way to get a specific amount of wallets,
if I don't want this default amount?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`Wallet.fromMnemonic`](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/single-page/#/v5/api/signer/-%23-Wallet.fromMnemonic)
function from ethers.js to do this.

Within `hardhat.config.js`,
or anywhere where you import the `hre` variable,
you can do so by invoking it like so:
`hre.ethers.Wallet.fromMnemonic(mnemonic, derivationPath?, wordList?)`

This function is used to generate a *single* wallet.
The function's second argument is the BIP-32 *derivation path*.
Since the one that you are using in config is `m/44'/60'/0'/0`,
then by default the function will append `/0`,
resulting in `m/44'/60'/0'/0/0` to generate the 1st wallet.

If you want to generate another one,
you could specify `m/44'/60'/0'/0/1` (with `/1` appended).

To generate a specific number of wallets,
simply do the above in a loop,
changing the final index in the derivation path in each iteration.

For example, the following function will obtain 10:

```js
function getSigners(amount = 40) {
  // getting seed phrase and derivation path from the hardhat config
  const { mnemonic, path } = hre.network.config.accounts
  return [...Array(amount).keys()].map((i) =>
    hre.ethers.Wallet.fromMnemonic(mnemonic, `${path}/${i}`)
      .connect(hre.ethers.provider),
  )
}
```